# QopenGLTexture with Target2DArray

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm trying to work with 2D array textures in qt with QOpenGLTextures, I want to send multiple images to the shader to do some processing between each frame. this is what I have so far and for debugging I'm just working with  first two images:

```
std::vector< QImage* > vtextureImgs;
vtextureImgs.resize(2);

QImage *textures0 = new QImage(m_dataPath + "/" +fileslist[0]);
m_width         =   textures0->width();
m_height        =   textures0->height();
m_QImgFormat    =   textures0->format();
vtextureImgs[0] =   textures0;

QImage *textures1 = new QImage(m_dataPath + "/" +fileslist[1]);
vtextureImgs[1] =   textures1;


GLsizei layerCount = 1;
GLsizei mipLevelCount = 1;




SAFE_DELETE(m_GLTexture);
m_GLTexture = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target::Target2DArray);
m_GLTexture->destroy();
m_GLTexture->create();

m_GLTexture->bind(); 

m_GLTexture->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Nearest);
m_GLTexture->setMagnificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Nearest);

m_GLTexture->setLayers(layerCount);


// m_GLTexture->setSize(m_width,m_height,1 );
m_GLTexture->setWrapMode(QOpenGLTexture::ClampToEdge);

m_GLTexture->setData(0, 0, QOpenGLTexture::RGB, QOpenGLTexture::UInt16, vtextureImgs[0]);

m_GLTexture->bind(0);


if(m_ShaderProgram!=nullptr)
{
    m_ShaderProgram->bind();
    m_ShaderProgram->setUniformValue("bgTexSampler",0);
    m_ShaderProgram->setUniformValue("rows",1);
    m_ShaderProgram->setUniformValue("cols",2);
    m_ShaderProgram->release();

}
```

but it gives me segmentation error when I call glTexSubImage3D . any idea on what is wrong here? and also how to set uniform value for this type of texture? My class is inherited from QOpenGLWidget class.

Edit: the segmentation fault is fixed with inheriting from QOpenGLFunctions. strange that I didn't have this problem with simple 2D textures. 
now I only get a black screen instead of the texture that I sent to the shader. Here is how my paintGL looks like:

```
    QMatrix4x4 projectionMatrix, modelMatrix, viewMatrix;

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

projectionMatrix.ortho(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
modelMatrix.setToIdentity();
viewMatrix.setToIdentity();

makeCurrent();
m_ShaderProgram->bind();

if(m_GLTexture->isCreated())
{

    m_GLTexture->bind();

    m_ShaderProgram->setUniformValue("projectionMatrix", projectionMatrix);
    m_ShaderProgram->setUniformValue("ModelMatrix", modelMatrix);
    m_ShaderProgram->setUniformValue("viewMatrix", viewMatrix);
    m_ShaderProgram->setUniformValue("cameraPositionX",(float)m_vfCameraPosition.x());
    m_ShaderProgram->setUniformValue("cameraPositionY",(float)m_vfCameraPosition.y());

    const QVector3D vertices[4] = {
        QVector3D(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f),
        QVector3D(-1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f),
        QVector3D( 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f),
        QVector3D( 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)
    };

    const QVector2D texcoords[4] = {
        QVector2D(0.0f, 1.0f),
        QVector2D(0.0f, 0.0f),
        QVector2D(1.0f, 0.0f),
        QVector2D(1.0f, 1.0f)
    };

    const unsigned int indices[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

    m_ShaderProgram->enableAttributeArray("vertices");
    m_ShaderProgram->enableAttributeArray("vTexCoords");

    m_ShaderProgram->setAttributeArray("vertices", vertices);
    m_ShaderProgram->setAttributeArray("vTexCoords", texcoords);

    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);

    m_ShaderProgram->disableAttributeArray("vertices");
    m_ShaderProgram->disableAttributeArray("vTexCoords");

    m_GLTexture->bind(0);
}
 m_ShaderProgram->release();
```

and my shader:

```
uniform sampler2DArray bgTexSampler;
uniform int rows;
uniform int cols;
uniform float cameraPositionX;
uniform float cameraPositionY;
smooth in vec2 FragTexCoord;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(void)
{
   vec4 color = texture(bgTexSampler, vec3(FragTexCoord, 0));
   fragColor = vec4(color.rgb, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the seg fault?  How do you initialize the OpenGL functions?

Comment: this line causes seg fault: glTexSubImage3D(..)

Comment: @G.M. I'm using QOpenGLWidget and in the initialization I enable :  'glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY);'

Comment: No, I mean how do you fix up the function pointers such as `glTexSubImage3D`?  Are you using something like `GLEW` or `QOpenGLFunctions`?  And again, which line causes the seg fault?

Comment: @G.M. I have edited my question. I'm using QOpenGLWidget as I said. I'm not sure though if it's right to use glTexSubImage3D with that. but I couldn't find a good way to set this type of data with setData from QOpenGLTexture

Comment: Please take a look at an [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-textures-example.html).  In particular [glwidget.cpp](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-textures-glwidget-cpp.html).  You need to initialize the OpenGL function pointers themselves.  On `Qt` that can be achieved by calling `QOpenGLFunctions::initializeOpenGLFunctions()`.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks! the problem with seg fault is fixed. the problem is now that I get a black screen instead of the texture.